# Full page body background image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile

I have a webpage which has several collapsable divs, the thing is that when I open more than once, the height of the background image I have on my body gets broken, at the end of the page I get a black background and the background isn't covering the whole page.

How could I fix this?.

Regards

For my body on CSS I'm using this:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../img/fondo_pantalla_bandadelcarmen_mar.jpg) !important; 
    background-position:center center !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
    -moz-background-size: cover !important;
    -o-background-size: cover !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Comment: Please give HTML and jsfiddle

Comment: What's with all that `!important`?

Comment: I don't want to do and jsfiddle because it's impossible to add all the css and js I have, I'll put the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

For further reference see [This](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)